# Is there a way to force round to not have null in all entries generated?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

So far, I have an issue where sometimes round generates randomly as null in some entries, is there a way to edit the code where it must generate one of the 5 values in the array? Along with that, can anyone edit this code where the date only shows the year value as an integer, ignoring the month and day?

```
with populate_cup_matches as (
  insert into cup_matches 
  select generate_series(1,624680,1) as mid,
         ('{final,semi-final,quarter-final,16,32}'::text[])[random()*5] as round,
         'epoch'::date+'1 year'::interval*floor(random()*53) as year,
         floor(random()*1000000)::int as num_ratings,
         random()*10 as rating
  returning *
)
```

This one is a bonus, however is there a way where 'salah' can be generated randomly across the entire table and not in a row until 22218, and perhaps making the name value appear legit as a name instead of some code. Thank you

```
insert into public.played_in
select mid,
       case when mid<=22218
          then 'salah'||(gen_random_uuid()::varchar(25))
          else gen_random_uuid()::varchar(30) 
       end as name,
       year,
       random()*11 as position
from populate_cup_matches limit 135960
returning *;
```

I tried to do a few solutions, but Im quite new to coding, so I apologise if I appear like I'm asking trivial questions.

Comment: 2023 is an integer. A date column cannot hold an integer value, just like an integer column cannot hold a date value. A date consists of year & month & day - always. A timestamp or datetime has those and smaller time units - always.  You **can format the display** of a date column to show only the year, but that does not affect the stored values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can fix the NULLs in the column "round" by using `floor(random()*5)+1` because you can't get a text array value for index 0. With respect to names try either https://mockaroo.com/ or http://randat.com/ to get a list of names then seed your result from that.

Regarding "Salah" (as in Mo Salah?) I cannot guaratee a specific number of rows will have that string, but below is a suggestion based on the remainder after division by 3 (approx 1/3) of the rows - "maybe".

```
WITH populate_cup_matches AS (
  SELECT generate_series(1, 20) AS mid,
         ('{final,semi-final,quarter-final,16,32}'::text[])[floor(random()*5)+1] AS round,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 'epoch'::date + '1 year'::interval * floor(random()*53)) AS year,
         floor(random()*1000000)::int AS num_ratings,
         random()*10 AS rating
),
names AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS rnd
  FROM (VALUES
        ('Adrian', 'Wilson'),
        ('Brad', 'Hawkins'),
        ('Arnold', 'Nelson'),
        ('Briony', 'Elliott'),
        ('Kristian', 'Richards'),
        ('Michael', 'Holmes'),
        ('Roman', 'Douglas'),
        ('Edith', 'Rogers'),
        ('Arianna', 'Gibson'),
        ('Abraham', 'Richardson'),
        ('Byron', 'Davis'),
        ('Tess', 'Crawford'),
        ('George', 'Miller'),
        ('Freddie', 'Casey'),
        ('Haris', 'Reed'),
        ('Marcus', 'Barrett'),
        ('Julian', 'Hawkins'),
        ('Carlos', 'Clark'),
        ('Madaline', 'Johnston'),
        ('Charlotte', 'Williams')
       ) AS names (first_name, last_name)
)
SELECT mid, round, num_ratings
       , CONCAT(n.first_name, ' ', CASE WHEN num_ratings % 3 = 0 THEN 'Salah' ELSE n.last_name END) AS name
       , year
FROM populate_cup_matches pcm
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT first_name, last_name
  FROM names
  WHERE rnd = 1 + (random() * (pcm.num_ratings % 20))::integer
) AS n ON true
```

| mid | round | num_ratings | name | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | quarter-final | 93153 | Arianna Salah | 1997 |
| 3 | 32 | 978044 | Arnold Nelson | 2012 |
| 3 | 32 | 978044 | Michael Holmes | 2012 |
| 5 | 32 | 630775 | Carlos Clark | 2008 |
| 6 | semi-final | 424009 | Marcus Barrett | 1982 |
| 6 | semi-final | 424009 | Julian Hawkins | 1982 |
| 7 | 16 | 21215 | Edith Rogers | 1998 |
| 8 | final | 494013 | Abraham Salah | 1977 |
| 10 | 16 | 266064 | Kristian Salah | 1978 |
| 11 | semi-final | 739711 | Kristian Richards | 2021 |
| 13 | final | 395580 | Arnold Salah | 1978 |
| 14 | quarter-final | 516702 | Michael Salah | 2000 |
| 16 | semi-final | 150100 | Arnold Nelson | 1996 |
| 18 | 32 | 548702 | Michael Holmes | 1971 |
| 19 | 16 | 332677 | Freddie Casey | 1992 |
| 20 | quarter-final | 10274 | Arianna Gibson | 1983 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KH0hgSd3)

**nb** if you only want "year" as the column then "extract" the year from the generated date - but note that the column in now integer and NOT a date!